# Accessing order_info array within OpenCart

Tags: php, opencart

I am currently working on a new OpenCart payment module extension.

Within my `/opencart/upload/catalog/controller/payment/extension.php` path, I have an object creation like this:

```
// The public function getOrder() is now available
// under the model_checkout_order object
$order_info = $this->model_checkout_order->getOrder($order_id);
```

Following that object initialization, I am able to access the `order_info` array like this:

```
$order_info['payment_firstname']
```

The above line retrieves that order's user's `firstname` variable.

My question is - where do I find the list of `order_info` variables? I am trying to find the buyer's e-mail address, the product description, product ID, and more. I have tried looking through the entire OpenCart directory structure, but I could not find any relevant information other than the object declaration above.

Comment: Probably what are you missing in the end is the knowledge of [`var_dump`](http://php.net/var_dump) or [`print_r`](http://php.net/print_r) functions. Using these on object/array will print out it's properties/indexes and their values. I personally prefer `var_dump($var);` as it prints `string(0): ""` for empty string and `NULL` for null value whereas using simple `echo $var;` or `die($string_var);` will print nothing (empty space) in case of empty string or null value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply you get buyer's email address

```
$order_info['email'];
```

If you want product details use following customized query.

```
$order_product_query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "order_product WHERE order_id = '" . (int)$order_id . "'");
foreach ($order_product_query->rows as $order_product) {
$order_product['product_id'];
$order_product['name'];
}
```

Comment: Do you know where the `getOrder()` function resides? I want to see all the queryable items.

Comment: find here **root/catalog/model/checkout/order.php**